# Store column result in variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, alias

I have fetched columns using the following SQL statement (I am using PDO):

```
$query = 'SELECT people.firstname,people.lastname,makes.make,cars.price
          FROM MyCars cars
          JOIN AllUsers people ON user.id = cars.userID
          JOIN AllMakes makes ON make.id = cars.makeID
          ORDER BY cars.price ASC LIMIT 0,1';

$statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I am try to store certain columns that have been retrieved into a variable for example storing the column 'firstname' from the AllUsers table into a variable '$firstname' is this possbile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns an associative array, where each column is in an element whose key is the column name. So if you do:

```
$row = yourfunc();
```

then you can do:

```
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
```

Comment: Thanks dude:) If I was to change the SQL statement to retrieve 3 rows so changing 'LIMIT 1' to 'LIMIT 3' how would i store certain rows, for example the 1st row of the execution and then the 2nd row. How would I do that?

Comment: You're only fetching one row in the function. You could use `fetchAll()` to get all the rows, then you'll get a 2-dimensional array, and you could write a loop that gets the `firstname` column from each row.